# How magento 1.9 Decrease Stock quantity when order was placed

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

How magento 1.9 Decrease Stock quantity when order was placed in magento admin catalog inventory Qty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go admin side `System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory`

And Set Yes in field `Decrease Stock When Order is Placed`and save on top right side button

Comment: but which file is responsible for decreasing Qty?

Comment: let me check and let you know

Comment: Pls check here app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Observer.php for this

Comment: Yes,in this subtractQuoteInventory method is calling